# Remove json object from json array

Tags: java, json

I've a JsonArray like:

```
"fields" : [
    {
      "name":"First Name",
      "id":1
    },
    {
      "name":"Middle Name",
      "id":2
    },
    {
      "name":"Last Name",
      "id":3
    }
]
```

I want to remove second JsonObject from above JsonArray. In order to do that I' wrote following code:

```
JsonArray fieldsObject =jsonObject.getJsonArray("fields");
fieldsObject.remove(fieldsObject.getJsonObject(2));
```

But second line throws error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Is there any way, I can remove JsonObject from a JsonArray?

Comment: Hi @TDHM, can you check this link? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/tTmv-US-HMI      , you are removing a data from a fix size array. Can you convert the JsonArray to an ArrayList?

Comment: Can you provide the api that you use. i.e Fully qualified name of JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

May be Your `JsonElement` or `JSONArray` is null.

`getJsonObject` returns a `JSONObject`.
 the remove method want `int`.

`UnsupportedOperationException`
if removing is not supported.

Try This :

```
JSONArray fieldsObject =jsonObject.getJsonArray("fields");
fieldsObject.remove(int index);
```

OR

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<fieldsObject.length();i++)
{
   if(i!=2)
   {
    result.put(fieldsObject.get(i)); 
   }
}
```

and assign result to original one

```
fieldsObject=result;
```

Comment: This also gives same error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 0):

> - `gson` library

Remove works for `gson` library version `2.3.1`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    String s = "{ \"fields\" : [ "+
            " {\"name\":\"First Name\",\"id\":1},"+
            "{\"name\":\"Middle Name\",\"id\":2},"+
            "{\"name\":\"Last Name\",\"id\":3}"+
            "]}";

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject json = parser.parse(s).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println("original object:"+json);
        JsonArray fieldsObject = json.getAsJsonArray("fields");
        System.out.println("Before removal :"+fieldsObject);
        Object remove = fieldsObject.remove(1);
        System.out.println("After removal :"+fieldsObject);
    }
```

Output:

```
   original object:{"fields":[{"name":"First Name","id":1},{"name":"Middle Name","id":2},{"name":"Last Name","id":3}]}
Before removal :[{"name":"First Name","id":1},{"name":"Middle Name","id":2},{"name":"Last Name","id":3}]
After removal :[{"name":"First Name","id":1},{"name":"Last Name","id":3}]
```

> - `org.json` library

Remove works for `org.json` library

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String s = "{ \"fields\" : [ "+
            " {\"name\":\"First Name\",\"id\":1},"+
            "{\"name\":\"Middle Name\",\"id\":2},"+
            "{\"name\":\"Last Name\",\"id\":3}"+
            "]}";
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
            System.out.println("original object:"+json);
            JSONArray fieldsObject =json.getJSONArray("fields");
            System.out.println("Before removal :"+fieldsObject);
            Object remove = fieldsObject.remove(1);
            System.out.println("After removal :"+fieldsObject);
        }
```

Output:

```
original object:{"fields":[{"name":"First Name","id":1},{"name":"Middle Name","id":2},{"name":"Last Name","id":3}]}
Before removal :[{"name":"First Name","id":1},{"name":"Middle Name","id":2},{"name":"Last Name","id":3}]
After removal :[{"name":"First Name","id":1},{"name":"Last Name","id":3}]
```

Comment: Sanj, I checked it with `org.json` but `remove` method is not available for `JSONArray`. I'm using version `20090211`. Could you please let me know which version of `org.json` you are using?

Comment: I am using version 20160212

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove element from `JsonArray` as it does not support `remove()` method:

```
private static final class JsonArrayImpl extends AbstractList<JsonValue> implements JsonArray {
```

And `remove()` method's implementation comes from `AbstractList` :

```
public E remove(int index) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Instead why don't you create a separate data strucure array or list to hold the objects that you want?

By the way, the purpose of using `JsonArray` is to load json data in object form that is why it supports read methods but does not support modifications on the loaded data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using org.json library as mentioned by Sanj in the above post. We can remove the element from JSONArray as below. I placed the json content in the .txt file and read into the String object for constructing the JSONObject. Please refer the code below.

```
public class App{    
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{    

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("json.txt"));
    String jsonContent = "";
    String jsonLine;
    while((jsonLine=br.readLine())!=null){
        jsonContent+=jsonLine;
    }
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("fields");
    jsonArray.remove(1);
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
}
}
```